# Solving this double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I have the following double integral, and I am struggling to solve it.

$$\int_{0}^{1} y dy \int_{y}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}\left[f(x)+g(x)\right]h \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are known in their full analytic form. However, we do not have any information about the analytic form of the function $h\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

Could someone give me a hint as to how I can go about solving this? Also, let me know if my question is missing any information.

Comment: I don't understand. How can you hope to "solve" this when you know nothing about $h$? I can suggest a change of variables: $u=x$, $v=y/x$. Rewrite the double integral with the usual change of variables. (Note that $0\le u,v\le 1$, and the Jacobian isn't too bad.)

Comment: A bit confused. How does the $ u = x $ change in variable help?

Comment: It's the $y/x$ that helps, and $x$ is perfectly fine as the second variable.

Comment: Okay thank you. This helped, and I was able to get to the point where I can complete my work.

Comment: May I ask you to answer your own question by stating the prerequisites and your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ted Shifrin's comment, here is how I solved the problem. As I stated in my question, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are known.

$\int_{0}^{1}y \space dy \int_{y}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}\space[f(x)+g(x)] \space h(\frac{y}{x})$

Then,I changed the order of integration and got:

$\int_{0}^{1}x\space dx \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dy}{x} \frac{y}{x} [f(x)+g(x)]h(\frac{y}{x})$

At this point, I made a change of variable: $\frac{y}{x} = u \implies du = \frac{dy}{x}$ and $0 \leq u \leq 1$

$\int_{0}^{1}dx \space x \space[f(x)+g(x)] \int_{0}^{1}du\space u \space h(u)$

As it turns out, for the $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ given to me, the $x$ integral simply gives 0.